# Inconsistent results from difftime

Tags: r, datetime, date

```
> time1 = strptime("2010-03-01 00:15:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
> time2a = strptime("2010-03-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
> time2b = as.Date(time2a)
> difftime(time1, time2a)
Time difference of 15 mins
> difftime(time1, time2b)
Time difference of 5.25 hours
```

From the help page of difftime, date object (time2b) is accepted. Why is the result wrong (5.25 hours)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing `difftime` does is check for the tz argument.  If missing it uses:

```
if(missing(tx)) {
    as.POSIXct(time1)
    as.POSIXct(time2)
}
```

testing that:

```
> as.POSIXct(time2b)
[1] "2010-02-28 16:00:00 PST"
> as.POSIXct(time2a)
[1] "2010-03-01 PST"
```

So it applies my timezone offset to the `date` object.

```
> difftime(time1,time2a)
Time difference of 15 mins
> difftime(time1,time2b,tz='GMT')
Time difference of 15 mins
```

Comment: Thank you Justin. I just figured it out before I saw your reply.